Creating and using an ssl certificate from my Asus Router
I have been trying to create a secure link between my Ubuntu (Linux) operating system and my Asus AC66U-B1 router. I enabled the DDNS client in the router and set up a host name to allow me to log into my router with a secure address such as https://xxxxxx.asuscomm.com and I exported the 'Lets encrypt" certificate to my Ubuntu machine. The certificate issued was called: cert_key.tar. When unzipped, it contained 3 files: cert.crt + cert.pem + key.pem.
The problem is, I do not know what to do with these files so that I can use my new secure link to my router using my browser. (Firefox)
Can anyone please tell me how to install these files into Ubuntu (or maybe these files need to be installed into Firefox?)
Thank you
Clan

I'm pretty sure Firefox trusts Let's Encrypt certificates by default, the issue is you should tell the router to use that certificate; i.e. you should configure whatever web server is running on the router. The issue is not on Ubuntu's side. To be honest, if this is for your own private use, I would generate my own private certificate using openssl and hack the router into using it, then trust the certificate as a root authority on my machine, because this way I wouldn't need to regenerate it every 90 days.

I am not sure what you mean. I got the certificates from my Asus router. It issued them to me with the help of 'LetsEncrypt', so if my router issued them, how would I tell my router to use them?? It seems to me that I need to install these somewhere on Ubuntu or in Firefox as a handshake between me and the router. Very confusing how to use these.

Ah sorry, I didn't understand the router itself issued those files to you, so I suppose it would be using the certificate already? What happens when you visit the page using HTTPS, are you getting the yellow warning triangle? What happens if you click on "Advanced" / "Show certificate", does it show that the certificate is that issued by Let's Encrypt?
